# Is there a way to build multiple models and create relationship between the models and user in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have this method:

```
  def current_budget(user)
    total = 0
    user.transactions.each do |t|
      if t.income_or_expense
        total += t.amount
      else
        total -= t.amount
      end
    end
    total
  end
```

My goal is to write an RSpec test for this method. I want to create multiple transactions and assign them to a user such that when I send that user to this method, the method returns the sum of all transactions.

```
eg:
Transaction1: amount: 25, user_id: 1
Transaction2: amount: 30, user_id: 1
Transaction3: amount: 35, user_id: 1
user: user_id: 1

it { expect(current_budget(user)).to eq(90) }
```

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transactions
end
```

Transaction model

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: It's possible using factories like `factory_bot` or `fabrication`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build these objects and relate them to each other with any [Active Record association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) method.

In a simple way, you could just build transactions and create a new user with it:

```rb
let(:user) { User.create(transactions: transactions) }
let(:transactions) do
  [25, 30, 35].map do |amount|
    Transaction.build(amount: amount)
  end
end

it { expect(current_budget(user)).to eq(90) }
```

But creating objects one by one could become a pain in the neck. There are some gems that provide a great way to build objects, one of them is [factory_bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot).

If you [define a factory](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#defining-factories) `user` and `transaction`, you could just call them like that

```rb
let(:user) { create(:user, transactions: transactions) }
let(:transactions) do
  [25, 30, 35].map do |amount|
    build(:transaction, amount: amount)
  end
end

it { expect(current_budget(user)).to eq(90) }
```